# I could not perform an Automation immediately by PHP via SOAP

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, fuel-sdk, php, automationstudio

I created this PHP code and run this.

PHP Code

```
const OBJ_TYPE    = "Automation";
const ACTION_TYPE = "start";
const OBJECT_ID   = "[Automation's External Key]";

try {
    $authStub = new ET_Client();
    $props = array(
        'ObjectID'  => OBJECT_ID
    );
    $response = new ET_Perform($authStub, OBJ_TYPE, ACTION_TYPE, $props);
    var_dump($response);

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $ex->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Result

```
object(ET_Perform)#5 (6) {
  ["status"]=>
  bool(false)
  ["code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["message"]=>
  NULL
  ["results"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#8 (3) {
      ["StatusCode"]=>
      string(5) "Error"
      ["StatusMessage"]=>
      string(70) "Automation cannot be Performed. Automation has been marked as deleted."
      ["ErrorCode"]=>
      int(355004)
    }
  }
  ["request_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["moreResults"]=>
  NULL
}
```

Please advise me how to perform this automation?

Comment: Are you sure that the Automation exists? Judging from the error, it appears that it has been deleted.

Comment: >Are you sure that the Automation exists?
Yes, already exists.
Not delete.

Answer (score 2):

I modified PHP sample code after confirm this page named [starting-an-automation](https://github.com/mattcam/Salesforce-Marketing-Cloud-Developer-Edition-Recipes/blob/master/starting-an-automation.md#retrieve-automation-objectid)

PHP Code

```
require('../ET_Client.php');

const OBJ_TYPE        = "Automation";
const ACTION_TYPE     = "start";
const AUTOMATION_NAME = "[Automation name]";

try {
    $authStub = new ET_Client();

    // Get ObjectID
    $props = array(
        'ProgramID',
        'Name'
    );
    $filter = array(
        'Property' => 'Name',
        'SimpleOperator' => 'equals',
        'Value' => AUTOMATION_NAME
    );
    $automationInfo = new ET_Get($authStub, OBJ_TYPE, $props, $filter);
    var_dump($automationInfo);
    $objectID = $automationInfo->results[0]->ObjectID;

    // Perform automation immediately
    $props = array(
        'ObjectID' => $objectID
    );
    $response = new ET_Perform($authStub, OBJ_TYPE, ACTION_TYPE, $props);
    var_dump($response);

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $ex->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

Result

```
object(ET_Get)#5 (6) {
  ["status"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["message"]=>
  NULL
  ["results"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#12 (3) {
      ["PartnerKey"]=>
      NULL
      ["ObjectID"]=>
      string(36) "**[This is ObjectID]**"
      ["Name"]=>
      string(13) "STG_WEBYOYAKU"
    }
  }
  ["request_id"]=>
  string(36) "[request id]"
  ["moreResults"]=>
  bool(false)
}
object(ET_Perform)#8 (6) {
  ["status"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["code"]=>
  int(200)
  ["message"]=>
  NULL
  ["results"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    object(stdClass)#10 (1) {
      ["StatusCode"]=>
      string(2) "OK"
    }
  }
  ["request_id"]=>
  NULL
  ["moreResults"]=>
  NULL
}
```

So, I can perform automation immediately by PHP via soap-api successfully.

Comment: Like I said, you just needed to get the objectID :-)

Answer (score 1):

`OBJECT_ID` is not the Automation's External Key. You will need to retrieve the ObjectID for the Automation before you can run an Automation.

If you are programatically starting a specific Automation (or Automations) on a recurring basis, then you will only need to retrieve the ObjectID once as it won't change.

I've documented how to [retrieve an ObjectID for an Automation using the SOAP API here](https://github.com/mattcam/Salesforce-Marketing-Cloud-Developer-Edition-Recipes/blob/master/starting-an-automation.md#retrieve-automation-objectid). Assuming that the automation won't change, you can simply use a curl command to retrieve the ObjectID using the instructions that I've documented in the provided link.